# How to remove a MongoDB collection with a period at the end of the collection name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I've accidentally created a MongoDB collection with a period at the end of the name, and since it's prohibited it Mongo, I couldn't access database with GUI tools or delete/rename it with mongo shell.

MongoDB considers period as a namespace terminator, and empty namespace is not allowed.

How do I delete this thing?

Actual request that created the collection (Rails 3 / Mongoid 3.1.3 gem)

```
mongo_session.command({ 'update' => "561e580f7b05e08f86000002.", 'updates' => [{ upsert: true,  q: { _id: <some_id> }, u: { '$set' => <some_data> } }], 'writeConcern' => { 'w' => 0 } })
```

Edit:
Well, if anyone got the same problem, Mongo Management Studio could delete collection with invalid name.

Comment: Have you tried `Mongoid.master.collection("561e580f7b05e08f86000002.").drop`?

Comment: `Mongoid.master.collection("561e580f7b05e08f86000002.").drop

NoMethodError: undefined method "master" for Mongoid:Module`